# Problem when creating QR code with Google API, subject and content are not merged

Tags: html, google-api, qr-code

I have tinkered a VBA code to create a QR code from a Google API. Creating the QR code, downloading and imlpementing into the files works wonderfully. However, the API does not merge the subject and content for me. It always stops after the first "&".

Does anyone know why, or have an example URL?

https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=120x120&cht=qr&chl=mailto:test@email.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&body=This%20is%20the%20body

Tried everything, changed everything